# How to redirect folder/page.html to seperate page in htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, directory

I have the following .htaccess file which works fine, now I am trying to add another folder but that is not working. How can I do it ?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ page.php [QSA,L]
```

As you can see in the above htaccess it simply matches any *.html and sends to page.php

Now i want to add another line for somefolder/somepage.html and that should redirect to post.php but the problem is that first one does'nt have any folder and second has folder but both have .html so first condition triggers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a chance that a request for `<something>.html` could map to a real file? (I doubt it could map to a directory?)

Comment: If <something>.html physically exists then it will show that. The lines RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f checks if physical file exists or not.

Comment: Yes, I get that. My point is... if you don't actually have physical files of the form `<something>.html` (since this would seem to be a PHP driven site, so having `.html` files as well wouldn't necessarily be the norm) then checking that the request does not map to a file is unnecessary and wasteful. Likewise, checking that a request for `<something>.html` does not map to a directory would also seem unnecessary (do you have directories with a `.html` extension?!). The same for the "symbolic link" check.

Comment: Filesystem checks are relatively "expensive", so if they aren't needed; don't use them (certainly not before every directive). Removing the filesystem checks (when not needed) simplifies the directives and makes it more performant.

Comment: Maybe, but its better to be safe that errors popping up.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to either change the order of rules, or add a condition, or use more specific rules, right?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/.+\.html$ $1/post.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+\.html$ page.php [QSA,L]
```

Or, if you need a more specific, less generic approach for that specific folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/?somefolder/.+\.html$ somefolder/post.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+\.html$ page.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Hi,I'm trying to add 3rd criteria and its not working, can you please help ? My code is following: 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# WORKING - Check if its a product eg. /some-folder/some-product.html
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/.+\.html$ product.php [QSA,L]

# WORKING - Check if its a page eg. /some-page.html
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+\.html$ page.php [QSA,L]

# NOT WORKING - Check if its category eg. /some-folder
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+\$ category.php [QSA,L]

Comment: Sorry, but please ask this in a new, separate question. You can refer to this question if it helps keeping things short. The reason is that separate things should get answered separately and also that it is impossible to read code passages in comments here.