# 3rd rule in .htaccess to redirect to specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My code is following, the first 2 rules are working fine, but I'm unable to work the 3rd one(Check if its category eg. /some-folder) page should be served by category.php file. Can anyone help?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# WORKING - Check if its a product eg. /some-folder/some-product.html
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/.+\.html$ product.php [QSA,L]

# WORKING - Check if its a page eg. /some-page.html
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+\.html$ page.php [QSA,L]

# NOT WORKING - Check if its category eg. /some-folder
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+\$ category.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It is interesting that you accepted the suggested rewriting rules from the question you asked about a month ago, but failed to precede _each_ rule with those conditions. Why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190732/how-to-redirect-folder-page-html-to-seperate-page-in-htaccess Please understand that those conditions will only get applied to the single rule they precede, not for any other rule. You should check the documentation for such details.

Comment: Have a try using `^/?[^/]+/?$` as a matching pattern in the last rule. The issue most likely is the escaping of the `$` in the attempted rule.

Comment: To clarify, the "category" `/some-folder` does **not** map to a physical directory on the filesystem? And what actually happens when making this request? What do you mean exactly by "not working".

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following edited htacess rules.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# WORKING - Check if its a product eg. /some-folder/some-product.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]*/)/([^.]*\.html)/?$ product.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# WORKING - Check if its a page eg. /some-page.html
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.html/?$ page.php [QSA,NC,L]

# EDITED RULES here.. - Check if its category eg. /some-folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/?$ category.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why you think reducing the matching pattern in the third rule should make a difference here?

Comment: And please remove those `NC` flags again, they don't really make much sense in this.

Comment: @arkascha, as per user shown urls this is written, if anything is missed, please feel free to tell.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say with `as per user shown urls this is written`, sorry.

Comment: @arkascha, as per user's comments `Check if its category eg. /some-folder` it was written.

Comment: I would suggest the pattern I posted in the comment to the question, the issue most likely is the escaping of the `$` in the attempted rule. So that should be fixed. The problem with removing the matching structure, as you suggest, is that the rule might collide with other rules. Because it matches _more_ than the original pattern.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replies but the suggested code is not working. The last rule is still not working.

Comment: I think none of my rules should collide with any coz its in this way: /folder/*.html  then /*.html and in the end /*

Comment: @TapanBhanot, could you please do mention which sample url isn't working?

Comment: In that case I suggest that you enable rewrite logging to learn what actually happens inside your rewriting engine on a step by step base. The documentation of the rewriting module explains how that works.

Comment: @TapanBhanot Also please make sure that you disabled the `MultiViews` feature.